# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Container)`, expected a ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, prisma

Raking my brain. Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the warning. I can comment out everything in both the page and component and still receive it. I would imagine it's something simple I am completely overlooking. Hoping one of the smarter people out there can kick me in the butt.

I pulled pretty much all of my code to thin things out. Have a prisma query in LatestSites. If I take out the query and async the error goes away.

page.tsx

```
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import LatestSites from './_components/LatestSites';

// export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Container sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
      <LatestSites />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

LatestSites.tsx

```
import prisma from '@/prisma/client';

const LatestSites = async () => {
  const sites = await prisma.site.findMany({
    orderBy: { startDate: 'desc' },
    take: 5,
    include: {
      assignedToUser: true,
    },
  });

  return <div>test</div>;
};

export default LatestSites;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross Allen makes a very good point and provides a good example that would work for something like `create-react-app`, however since this is tagged as Next.JS we can use some nice tooling provided.

---

In Next.JS 13+ (when using the app router) we can use the `use` function provided by React to call asynchronous code:

```js
import { use } from "react";
import prisma from '@/prisma/client';

async function getSites() {
  return await prisma.site.findMany({
    orderBy: { startDate: 'desc' },
    take: 5,
    include: {
      assignedToUser: true,
    },
  })
}

export default function Home() {
  const sites = use(getSites());
  return <div>test</div>;
}
```

---

In Next.JS 9.3 - 12 (or 13+ using the pages router) we can use the [`getServerSideProps` function](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) provided by Next.JS to call asynchronous code on the server side:

```js
import { use } from "react";
import prisma from '@/prisma/client';

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const sites = await prisma.site.findMany({
    orderBy: { startDate: 'desc' },
    take: 5,
    include: {
      assignedToUser: true,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      sites: sites,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

export default function Home({ sites }) {
    return <div>test</div>;
}
```

Comment: Giving this a shot.

Comment: It's really weird. Still getting the same warning using your code above for Next.JS 13+. I mean.. it's all working without issue except for that warning. I did read elsewhere that it was just a dev error that you wouldn't see in production. Just driving me a little crazy. Especially when the error ceases when I wrap the component in a div in page.tsx. Will give useEffect a shot above to see if that changes anything.

Comment: forgot that useEffect and useState are only client side so that's not going to work in a server component. hmmm I dunno..

Comment: @RawAnimal then I have to assume the warning arises from somewhere else in the application. You said "I can comment out everything in both the page and component and still receive it" which would point to somewhere else in the application, that you don't include in your post.

Comment: What I meant by commenting everything out is also removing the db query and the async on the function. If I take everything down to the most basic component the error goes away.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out and had to move on. Was able to surpress the warning by wrapping the component in a div. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your issue and I don't get that error. Your `LatestSites` component is a valid react server component and you are totally allowed to make it an `async` function and make a call to prisma in it which blocks the rendering of the component till the prisma query resolves.
Does wrapping `LatestSites` in a `Suspense` solve your issue?

Comment: I'm not great with server components as I haven't yet gotten a chance to use them, but is there a possibility that @RawAnimal hasn't properly configured the component as a server component

Comment: @Zachiah in Next.js all components are server components by default unless you add the `use client` directive. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs

Comment: it depends on the version of next.js he uses @Anatol

Comment: hmm I guess that makes sense. Does this apply even if they are using the old folder structure (I thought there was some kind of old folder structure that made old behavior apply to prevent breakage)

Comment: @gear4 @Zachiah he used `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';` which is only supported in the app router

Comment: fair - but as it's commented out I'm not leaning either way, rather playing it safe

Comment: @gear4 his file name is `page.tsx` which is the file naming convention in the `app` router. Also you can see from his folder structure that `page.tsx` is in the same directory as `_components/LatestSites.tsx` directory, which is also only supported in the `app` router.

Comment: aha got it - some nicities from app router :)

Comment: strange.. I was able to surpress the warnings by adding a div around the LatestSites component. That's just a bandaid though. Going to try the suggestions above to see if it fixes. Will circle back.

Comment: @Anatol Not familiar with Suspense. Pretty new to all this stuff.